# can not add audio onto processing

Tags: processing

I added an audio file in processing, but when I ran it the program just reminded:

> Could not run the sketch (Target VM failed to initialize). Make sure
>   that you haven't set the maximum available memory too high.

The size of the file I added was only 266KB and the format was `wav`. What confused me was I had add an audio file named `love.mp3` whose size is 4.01MB and the program ran normally.
Here is the code:

```java
Minim minim;
AudioPlayer player;
AudioInput input;
void setup(){
  size(400,400);
  minim = new Minim(this);
  player = minim.loadFile("transformer.wav");
  input = minim.getLineIn();
}

void draw(){ }

void mousePressed(){
  player.play();
}

void mouseReleased(){
  player.close();
  player = minim.loadFile("transformer.wav");
}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether Minim supports WAV files ?

Comment: Also, what is your available Memory set to in your Preferences ?

Comment: please show the entire stack trace, not just its conclusion: at what point in starting the sketch do you get your error, and which line have you isolated as causinng that?